# How does R-CNN and AlexNet compare?

Tags: faster-rcnn, alex-net

I know AlexNet does object classification in images [categories] and R-CNN does object localization [category and bounding box].
How does R-CNN and AlexNet compare?

Are they used for the same purpose or R-CNN does more? Does R-CNN use Alexnet as a sub-module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got most of it from the way you wrote your question.

> How does R-CNN and AlexNet compare?
>
> Are they used for the same purpose or R-CNN does more?

They are different things. AlexNet is a CNN architecture, i.e a neural network with a specific set of layers. R-CNN is multistep method that does object localization and classification using a search algorithm with a CNN (of any architecture) and a SVM.

> Does R-CNN use Alexnet as a sub-module?

R-CNN can use AlexNet, or other CNN architectures, as its' feature extractor.